# PHP file as server on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, http, httpresponse, get-request

I have a php file that acts as a server and must return responses to requests that are sent to it.
this is the request :

```
//request parameters
    $request_args = array(
        'body' => [
            'action' => 'version',
            'type' => $this->product_type,
            'name' => $this->product_type == 'plugin' ? $this->plugin_slug : $this->theme,
        ],
        'timeout'     => '5',
        'redirection' => '5',
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'blocking'    => true,
        'headers'     => array(
            'content-type' => 'text/plain',
        ),
        'cookies'     => array(),
    );

    //get request
    $response = wp_remote_get($this->server_url,$request_args);
```

and this is the server code :

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/ProductInfo.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/VersionDetector.php';

use provider\ProductInfo;
use provider\VersionDetector;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if(isset($_GET['action']))
{
    switch($_GET['action'])
    {
        case 'version':
            VersionDetector::version();
            break;
        case 'info':
            ProductInfo::info();
            break;
    }
}
```

**The server URL is: http://localhost/update%20server/updater.php

the request is made successfully and the response code is 200 but the problem is that on the server side, I have no access to the parameters of sent request (request body), meaning that $_GET['action'] is undefined.
and Also the response body is empty even if I put an echo or return statement to the very top of the file.

I've also tested sending parameters as query strings by concatenating them to the end of the server URL but still got the same output.

this is the var_dump result of returned response :

```
array(6) {
  ["headers"]=>
  object(WpOrg\Requests\Utility\CaseInsensitiveDictionary)#2460 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(5) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(29) "Wed, 19 Apr 2023 07:48:39 GMT"
      ["server"]=>
      string(46) "Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/8.1.6"
      ["x-powered-by"]=>
      string(9) "PHP/8.1.6"
      ["content-length"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["content-type"]=>
      string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  }
  ["body"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["response"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["message"]=>
    string(2) "OK"
  }
  ["cookies"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["filename"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_response"]=>
  object(WP_HTTP_Requests_Response)#2545 (5) {
    ["data"]=>
    NULL
    ["headers"]=>
    NULL
    ["status"]=>
    NULL
    ["response":protected]=>
    object(WpOrg\Requests\Response)#2467 (10) {
      ["body"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["raw"]=>
      string(215) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2023 07:48:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/8.1.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.6
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

"
      ["headers"]=>
      object(WpOrg\Requests\Response\Headers)#2469 (1) {
        ["data":protected]=>
        array(5) {
          ["date"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(29) "Wed, 19 Apr 2023 07:48:39 GMT"
          }
          ["server"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(46) "Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/8.1.6"
          }
          ["x-powered-by"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(9) "PHP/8.1.6"
          }
          ["content-length"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(1) "0"
          }
          ["content-type"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
          }
        }
      }
      ["status_code"]=>
      int(200)
      ["protocol_version"]=>
      float(1.1)
      ["success"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["redirects"]=>
      int(0)
      ["url"]=>
      string(44) "http://localhost/update%20server/updater.php"
      ["history"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["cookies"]=>
      object(WpOrg\Requests\Cookie\Jar)#2480 (1) {
        ["cookies":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    ["filename":protected]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anything showing when you `var_dump($_GET)` in the server code?

Comment: @droopsnoot No, nothing gets shown on the page.